# Weird error that doesn't make any sense c++ simple for/while loop on vector

Tags: c++, loops

In a function that I called addzerosatfront all I want to do is add zeros at the front of a `Typedef vector<bool> bitstring` and thus resize the vector with zeros at the front. But the loop runs for less than I want, by 2, 3 or 4 (or more) itereations depending on the size of the vecotors. I have tried debugging but I have no clue where this weird error might be occuring. I have tried it with for and while loops, but that doesn't change anything...

```
void addzerosatfront(bitstring& a, size_t n){
if(a.size()>=n) return;
cout<<a.size()<<endl<<n<<endl;
cout<<n-a.size()<<endl;
int i=0;
while(i<n-a.size()){
    ++i;
    a.insert(a.begin(), 0);
}}
```

EDIT: I solved it with

```
bitstring x(size_t(n-a.size()), 0);
a.insert(a.begin(), x.begin(), x.end());
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Please [clarify](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48962907/edit). Don't use vector of bools.

Comment: Why do you increase `i`? Please share the thought that went into adding `++i` to that loop.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, consider using a [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You increase `i` and decrease `n-a.size()` in one iteration. As a result if you want initially to add `n-a.size()` zeroes, in reality you add `(n-a.size()) / 2` zeros. Try `while(a.size() < n)`.

There is a better solution.

```
a.insert(a.begin(), n-a.size(), 0);
```